# CSS background color not properly working

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML code

```css
header1 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<header1>
  <h1> My most favorite album is Dirty Sprite 2 by Future</h1>
  <img src="images/cover.jpg" alt="DS2 Cover" width="300" height="300">
  <audio controls>
            <source src = "audio/14%20-%20Trap%20Niggas.mp3" type = "audio/mpeg">
        </audio>
</header1>
```

However, it does not set the entire header1 to the color red? There's just a red bar
Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems here.

The most obvious is that header1 is not a recognised HTML tag. (your code would probably fail in most validators).

Browsers tend to be very forgiving though so they will do their best to render your page. However, they don't know what header1 is so they have no in built styling for it.

For the (legal) header tag they will have inbuilt styling, and you can find out what that is by looking at your browser dev tools styles for the element. For example, Chrome has just shown me it assumes display: block as the default.

If you were to give your header1 a style of display: block it will show the background as red as you want. But better to use 'legal' HTML and use the header tag instead of header1 and perhaps a class to do the styling if this is the only header with background red.

Answer (score -1):

header1 is not a valid name for an [html tag](https://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/default.ASP) try using a **div** and set an **id** or a **class** for it so it would be easier to refference it in css

```css
#header1 {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="header1"> your other code goes here </div>
```